# How to normalize a 2d histogram in python?

Tags: python, histogram

I'm trying to plot a 2d histogram. The histogram is basically a galaxy and I have the points of each luminous point. I have plotted the histogram but it's not properly normalized, as the values of the colorbar should go from 0 to 1. How can I fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import kde

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1, figsize=(20, 8))

data1 = pd.read_csv('mydata.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)

az1 = data1[0]
el1 = data1[1]

nbins = 250
hist1 = axes[0].hist2d(az1, el1, bins=nbins, cmap='magma', density=True)
 
fig.colorbar(hist1[3], ax = axes)
```

Comment: did you try to use the norm parameter:   `hist2d(az1, el1, bins=nbins, cmap='magma', density=True, norm=mcolors.PowerNorm(1))` with `import matplotlib.colors as mcolors`

Comment: @ymmx I've tried to add that piece to my code but it doesn't even compilate with that, it takes a lot of time and the program doesn't respond

Comment: @ymmx apparently now it has compiled but no change has appeared in the plot, that piece of code doesn't change anything in my histogram

Comment: @ymmx any idea?

Comment: @ymmx I have tried with "hist1 = axes[0].hist2d(az1, el1, bins=nbins, cmap='magma', density=True, norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0))", but the plot turns completely black then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with the function `hist2D`but I didn't find a way to normalized the result with it. So what I suggest is using the hitrogram from the `numpy` modul: `np.nistogram2d` where you can extract the result and then normalized the output before display it.
Here an example with random numbers:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import kde

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1, figsize=(20, 8))

# data1 = pd.read_csv('mydata.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
N=10000
az1 = np.random.random(N)
el1 = np.random.random(N)

nbins = 250
hist1 = axes[0].hist2d(az1, el1, bins=nbins, cmap='magma', density=True)
fig.colorbar(hist1[3], ax = axes)


H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(el1, az1, bins=(nbins, nbins),density=True )
# H_normalized = H/float(az1.shape[0]) # the integral over the histogrm is 1
H_normalized = H/H.max((0,1)) # the max value of the histogrm is 1
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]

im = axes[1].imshow(H_normalized, extent=extent, cmap='magma', interpolation='none',origin ='lower')
fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes[1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I have tried it, the first subplot appears, but the second one appears completely empty

Comment: It works for me with the random data. Did you try with your data directly?

Comment: ok, i have fixed the problem, but the second subplot appers rotated 90 degrees, how can i fix this?

Comment: I updated the code. I just inverted el1, az1 in histogram2d

Comment: this doesn't work either, now it's rotated 180 degrees, i mean, now x axis is okay but not y axis, the y axis has the highest values in the bottom when it should have the lowest

Comment: I mean, the image is corrrect now, but not the values of the y-axis

Comment: Yes, sorry I forget to modify the extent also. It is done now.